# Android make a copy of an ImageView instance

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView that I laid out in XML, but I need to later programmatically add overlay images to the first. I was wondering if there is an easy way to make a new ImageView instance based on one I already have? That way I don't need to reset all the layout constraints and whatnot.

I suspect there isn't a simple way to do this, but I just thought I would throw the question out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no really a simple way to do that. What you can do is either:

1. Create a new `ImageView` instance and copy all needed parameters (`image`, `background`, `scaleType`, `LayoutParams`, etc.) from the `ImageView` inflated previously from xml.

or

2. Move your `ImageView` from your original xml (lets name it `A`) to a separate xml (that would contain only this `ImageView`, lets name it `B`). In your `A` xml use `include` tag to make it contain your `ImageView`. And then in your code you can just inflate a "copy" of your `ImageView` from `B` xml.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating another imageview. Just replace images. If you wanna play with your images there is a java library for it.

[image4j](http://image4j.sourceforge.net/) ---
[iImagej](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/)

Use these libraries, create new image and use your imageview.